# Почему после закрытия окна в PyQt остается висеть его процесс?

Tags: python

Перехожу потихоньку с Tkinter на PyQt, пробую примеры. Сразу появились вопросы...
Почему после закрытия окна в PyQt остается висеть его процесс? Вот пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class PyQtDialog(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)

    def info(self, title="Title:", text="Text..."):
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, title, text)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok:
            return True
        else:
            return False

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

dialog = PyQtDialog()
dialog.info()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Окно закрывается, но его процесс продолжает жить. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю, что в этой строке

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

формально, в этой строке запускается цикл обработки сообщений. Но они то не приходят...

вот так работает:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо!